# How to schedule objects in list

Tags: c, performance

Suppose I have several lists with the different priority.
Each list contains objects with start time and end time.

**list 1(high pirority):**  obj1(str=0, end=2) -> obj2(str=100, end=102)-> ...

**list 2(mid  priority):**  obj1(str=0, end=1) -> obj2(str=20, end=21) -> obj3(str=40,end=41) -> obj4(str=60, end=61) -> obj5(str=80, end=81) -> obj6(str=100,end=101)

**list 3(low  priority):** obj1(str=0, end=2) -> obj2(str=15, end=17) -> obj3(str=30,end=32) -> obj4(str=45, end=47) -> obj5(str=60, end=62) -> obj6(str=75,end=77) -> obj7(str=90, end=92) -> obj8(str=105, end=107) ->

And there is a scheduler which fetches one object at a time according to priority.
Rules are:
(1)on obj at a time, no overlapping is allowed.
(2)if obj overlapped, the one with higher priority will be fetched.

The expected fetch order would be:
list1 obj1(0~2) -> list3 obj2(15~17) -> list2 obj2(20~21) -> list3 obj3(30~32) -> list2 obj3 (40~41) -> ...

Is there any quick algorithm to generate the final list as shown above, instead of looping all the obj inside all the list?
Or is there any structure which simplifies this process?

Comment: You're basically doing a merge sort, but with twist: some of the items are dropped.

Comment: IMHO, you should process it *by hand* by looking for next event (shorter start time with higher priority), then skipping in other lists events that could be at a passed time and iterate. And you should show what you have tried if you want more precise answers